# Is there a way to automatically collect gmail id in webform and Google sites?

Tags: google-apps-script

1. Is there a way to automatically collect gmail id of the person filling google-docs web-form?

   (Something equivalent to Google apps "automatically collect username" in web forms).
2. If I have a google app site shared with normal gmail user or google group, is there a way to run GAS to automatically collect gmail id?

This is what I am trying to do:

1. I create public google docs web forms (online tests)
2. Any student with link can take test, but I would like to automatically collect his gmail id.
3. I am running private google app site, shared with students_list@googlegroups.com. If a particular student of this list visits my website, he will be shown logged in using as student1@gmail.com

I would like to provide a "Show Results Button" on website that would lookup automatically detect student1@gmail.com and look up data from spreadsheet form from 1.

Answer (score 0):

1). The simple answer is no. The obvious fallback method is to ask for the user's email address explicitly. This is kept so because of security reasons.

2) The answer again is no. You can get the email address only if your script is within a domain and the logged on users belong to that domain.

YOu can have a look [Ryan Boyd's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063749/how-do-i-get-an-access-token-using-urlfetchapp-with-gas) and use something similar to get explicit access to the user's email id.