# how to get the email adress of the sender

Tags: email, google-apps-script, sender

I need to generate a report on the list of messages and the sender of a letter, I can extract the theme of letters, but not understanding how to get the sender's address for each letter, the report turned out to be:

topic: hello From: frank@gmail.com

topic: your basket from: jerry@facebook.com

```
  function myFunction() {
      var emailAddress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
      var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();


      var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
      for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        output.append(threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject()+" from:"+'\n');
      }


      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,"Mail Report", output.getContent()

        );
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Thank you for your answers, the solution was simple

```
   function myFunction() {
      var emailAddress = "example@email.com" ;
      var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();

      var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
      var senderEmail = messages[0].getFrom();


      var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
      for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        messages = threads[i].getMessages()
        senderEmail = messages[0].getFrom();
        output.append(i + ".  " + threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject()+"   from:"+ senderEmail + '\n');
      }


      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,"Mail Report", output.getContent()

        );
    }
```

Example result:

1. Email Verification - Stack Overflow    from:Stack Overflow
2. Project Update #10: Double Fine Adventure by Double Fine and 2 Player Productions    from:Kickstarter

Comment: The code you've provided does not produce the output you've provided.  That being said, I *think* patto_chennai has answered your question, although I'm not sure any of us are sure what the question is.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand what you are looking to do, then I believe you could get the messages from the thread, and then the sender from the message

```
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
var senderEmail = messages[0].getFrom();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I thought about it and realized how to use this method in a script

Answer (score 0):

```
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('inbox');
var threads = label.getThreads();


for(i in threads)
{

  threads[i].getMessages()[0].getFrom()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
in oauthScopes.(appscript.json file)

you can get more details in this link
[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/scopes#gmail_add-on_scopes)

Answer (score -1):

For reasons of security, you cannot get the email using `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` if you are on a consumer Google account. It works only when the script is owned by a Google Apps user and the visitor belongs to the same domain.

However, you can try what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063749/how-do-i-get-an-access-token-using-urlfetchapp-with-gas)

Comment: Thanks, I just had to read the addresses of senders in the Inbox of my mail :)