# How to get user profile picture from Google Chat Bot using Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chat

I'm a bit new to Google App Script and I can't find how to do it. I am creating a Google Chat bot using Google App Script and I want to get the profile picture of the user who messaged the bot, preferably the link instead of the image itself since I will be passing the image to a website.

Edit: I do know that Google has an API to get the user photo like [this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users.photos/get), if I'm an admin - which I'm not - or like [this](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)
but I don't know how to use it in App Script or if it's even possible to do so. From what I understand I need to have the user's ID which I have no idea how to get. I have also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476318/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-a-domain-users-profile-image-using-google-apps-script) question however the links that could be helpful for me doesn't work anymore. If it helps I also know their email address, I just need to get the account ID from there. I don't mind using other APIs that require OAuth to do this. If it helps I also know their email address, I just need to get the account ID from there.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone would need the answer in the future what I did was add `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"` to my scopes and added this to my code

```
var accessToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + accessToken + '';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
response =  JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var image = response['picture'];
```

The image then returns a link to the public profile picture.

Comment: This approach will only give you the data for the authenticated user. Wasn't your question how to get the data of the user who triggered the Chat event?

Comment: Yes I wanted to get the data of the user who triggered the chat event and it works as I intended though the resolution is a bit lower than expected which is not a problem for me. I think it works because every person who uses the chat bot is an authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

This information cannot be retrieved with Chat API.

#### Reference:

Chat API [User resource](https://developers.google.com/chat/reference/rest/v1/User) doesn't include any information about the profile picture:

```
{
  "name": string,
  "displayName": string,
  "domainId": string,
  "type": enum (Type),
  "isAnonymous": boolean
}
```

#### File a feature request:

If you think this feature can be useful, I'd suggest requesting it in Issue Tracker using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=350158&template=1047215).