# "Publish to the web" for Document in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, web-publishing

Is there any plan to provide Google Apps Script capability for the "Files | Publish to the web..." menu item in a Google Document?

This has been asked before, but heck if I can find an answer.  To be clear, I don't mean setting the sharing or viewability of the Document itself, I mean the thing where a web page representation of the Document with its own link is generated.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a method for this, provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469509/publish-a-google-spreadsheet-through-google-apps-scripts).

First, add the service Drive API
[image: Apps Script add Drive API service]

```
var docId = "###"; // Please set this.
Drive.Revisions.update({published: true, publishedOutsideDomain: true, publishAuto: true}, docId, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible directly with GAS. However, using the Document List API and URLFetch with oAuth, you can, in theory make a document public on the web. Publish to the web option, per se, isn't available though.

Please see the following links for information and help

- [How do I get an access token using UrlFetchApp with GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063749/how-do-i-get-an-access-token-using-urlfetchapp-with-gas)
- https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#sharing_resources_with_the_public_the_rest_of_the_internet