# Programmatically get a Spreadsheet "Publish[ed] on the web"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

For the time being I believe this is a real wall I'm hitting my head on, but let's try:

Is there any way to programmatically set a spreadsheet to "Publish[ed] on the web" via GAS, or using any of the Google APIs (Google Spreadsheets, Google Docs List, etc.) and UrlFetch?

The goal is to access the sheet feed anonymously.

Please note that it is possible to make a sheet "public" (through the Google Docs List: it's a "sharing" option), or using GAS setAnonymousAccess() I think, but as far as I know, not "published", which is a different cup of tea (it's set manually through "File->Publish on the Web").  A "public" sheet has no feed, and a "published" one (it does not even need to be "public") has one.

Thanks.

Comment: This question has already been asked quite recently [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275062/publish-to-the-web-for-document-in-google-apps-script)