# How to make a multiple google sheets published to web and get the pubHTML link using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 800+ google sheets inside my google drive. I want to make these google sheets published to web using apps script and get the pubhtml link after.

The manual process of "publish to web" is go to file->publish to the web->publish. I want this to be automated using appscript. I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Have you read [how to publish to the web a spreadsheet using drive API and GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41743755/1330560)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will leave you this code, which can help you to publish automatically all those spreadsheets

```
function publishSheetsToWeb() {
 // Log the name of every file in the user's Drive.
 var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   // Check if it is a spreadsheet
   if(file.getMimeType() === 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'){
     try{
       var fileId = file.getId();
       // get the revisions and then get the last one of them
       var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId); 
       var lastRevisionId = revisions.items[revisions.items.length - 1].id;
       // get the resource and set the publish parameters
       var resource = Drive.Revisions.get(fileId, lastRevisionId);  
       resource.published = true;
       resource.publishAuto = true;
       resource.publishedOutsideDomain = true;
       // publish to the web
       Drive.Revisions.update(resource, fileId, lastRevisionId); 
     }  catch(err) {
       Logger.log(err); 
     }
   }
 }
}
```

### Notice

- To get the public URLs you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997579/how-to-get-the-id-for-a-published-to-the-web-spreadsheet-in-google-apps-scripts)
- Because you are trying to make public a lot of docs, be careful with the quotas limits. You can learn more about them [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)