# List of all tabs' "publish to web" links on a large googlesheet document (200 tabs)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, publish

Is there a way to get a list of each of the hyperlinks created by the "publish to web" function on google sheets without selecting each tab individually and copying and pasting to a spreadsheet/word document. Ideally the output being all my tab names (circa 200 of them) and the link.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: How does publish to the web create hyperlinks on a sheet?

Answer (score 0):

If all you wish is tab names then this is a list of tab names:

```
function getTabNames() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  Logger.log(ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName()).join(','))
}
```

You could use openById() if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to receive the Web Published URL for all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.
- You want to put the URLs to the Spreadsheet.

#### Issue and workaround:

When a Google Spreadsheet is published to the web, a URL like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml?gid=###&single=true` is obtained. But, in the current stage, unfortunately, this cannot be retrieved using a script and API. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50997579) By this, it is required to manually create the URL.

In this answer, I would like to propose 2 patterns for achieving your goal.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, a URL like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml?gid=###&single=true` is used. `2PACX-###` is not the Spreadsheet ID. Please be careful about this.

First, please publish to the web for your Spreadsheet, and retrieve the URL of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml?gid=###&single=true`. In this pattern , `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml` from `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml?gid=###&single=true` is used.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, please set your `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml` to `baseUrl`. When you use this script, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE()`. By this, the URLs are returned.

```js
function SAMPLE() {
  const baseUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml"; // Please modify this for your URL.

  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().map(s => `${baseUrl}?single=true&gid=${s.getSheetId()}`);
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the URL like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/### fileId ###/pubhtml` is used. In this case, Spreadsheet ID is used. By this, you are not required to do a hard copy of the URL.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. When you use this script, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE()`. By this, the URLs are returned.

```js
function SAMPLE() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const baseUrl = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/pubhtml`;
  return ss.getSheets().map(s => `${baseUrl}?single=true&gid=${s.getSheetId()}`);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this case, when the sheet is not published, you cannot access the URL. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [getSheetId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getsheetid)

Comment: Sorry, but not sure what this is doing. The execution works fine.. basically what I need, is on one tab (or a different sheet) is a list of all my tab names in column A, and in column B is the web address of the "Publish to Web" for each tab.

Comment: @IrishChristof Thank you for replying. From `The execution works fine`, I understood that the script worked. But I cannot understans `what I need, is on one tab (or a different sheet) is a list of all my tab names in column A, and in column B is the web address of the "Publish to Web" for each tab.`. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detail of your actual goal? By this, I would like to confirm it.