# Google Sheets Mulitple Publish to Web

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with 50+ rows of data. I am then using the Autocrat add-on to create 50 separate Google Sheets with the individual data. Autocrat produces a list of URLs to each document.

I would like to use these URLs to then publish each one to the web in bulk, and have the published URLs put back into this spreadsheet next to the current data (URL with a corresponding data row).

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you share link to this Autocrat add-on? You can use the Drive API to publish a Google Sheet. Check one of my recent questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469509/publish-a-google-spreadsheet-through-google-apps-scripts

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocrat/ppgnklghfnlijoafjjkpoakpjjpdkgdj

Comment: Where do you get the autocrat URLs? What do you mean by "publish each one on the web"? Like changing the permissions of the sheet to be available to the public?