# How to publish a Google Slides presentation from Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have built a Google Slides presentation using Google Apps Script.

```
var docId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();
var newDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(docId).setName(newDocName);
var newDocUrl = newDoc.getUrl(); // This gets the URL of the editing view. I want the presentation view.
```

How do I publish it then get the URL of the published presentation?

[Here are the docs.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation.html) I'm looking for something like:

```
var publishedNewDoc = newDoc.publish();
var newDocPublishedUrl = publishedNewDoc.getPublishedUrl();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You want to publish Google Slides using a script.
- You want to retrieve the published URL.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### Publishing Google Slides:

In order to publish the Google Docs, you can use the method of Revisions: update in Drive API. About this, you can see [a sample script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56469761) as one of several answers.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

```
var slidesId = "###"; // Please set this.
Drive.Revisions.update({published: true, publishedOutsideDomain: true, publishAuto: true}, slidesId, 1);
```

### Retrieving published URL:

When you publish manually the Google Slides to the web, you can see the URL like `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-###/pub`. Unfortunately, in the current stage, this URL cannot be retrieved. So as a workaround, the published URL can be retrieved using the file ID. The published URL with the file id for Google Slides is as follows.

```
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/### file ID ###/pub
```

- If you want to use the query parameter, please set it above URL.
- There are no methods for directly creating above URL, so please create it using a script.

### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Revisions: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions/update)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.