# Publish a Google Spreadsheet through Google Apps Scripts #2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to publish a web app through the script code. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469509/publish-a-google-spreadsheet-through-google-apps-scripts) but I can't make it work, maybe it's a slightly different situation. I have got a script that copies a spreadsheet: in the script, I want to publish the new copy of the spreadsheet as a web app and, if it's possibile, retrieve its public url (anyone should be able to access to it).

Here it is my code:

```
  // Make a copy of the spreadsheet
  var repliesFile = responseTemplate.makeCopy('risposte', newFolder);
  var repliesId = SpreadsheetApp.openById(repliesFile.getId());

  // pubblish the new copy as a web app
  Drive.Revisions.update({published: true, publishedOutsideDomain: true, publishAuto: true}, repliesId, 1);

  // of course, this doesn't work.. I need a way to get the web app public url of the new copy
  var webAppUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
```

I got an 404 error. What am I doing wrong? Drive Api v.2 is enabled in the script. Thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to publish the copied Spreadsheet.
- You want to retrieve the URL of the published Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this by modifying your script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I think that `repliesId` is not correct. It's the Spreadsheet object. Please use `repliesFile.getId()` as the file ID.
- Unfortunately, in the current stage, the URL like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml` cannot be retrieved. But you can `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=### spreadsheetId ###` as the URL of published Spreadsheet.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

##### From:

```
Drive.Revisions.update({published: true, publishedOutsideDomain: true, publishAuto: true}, repliesId, 1);
```

##### To:

```
var fileId = repliesFile.getId();
Drive.Revisions.update({published: true, publishedOutsideDomain: true, publishAuto: true}, fileId, 1);
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=" + fileId;
```

- `url` can be used as the URL of the published Spreadsheet.

#### Note:

- In this case, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.

#### References:

- [publish a Google Spreadsheet through Google Apps Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56469509)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Revisions: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions/update)

Comment: Wow, it was a very silly mistake on my part. Thank you very much. Now, the problem is that url point to a kind of public version of the spreadsheet (I can see all the data and the sheets inside), not the html output returned by the doGet() function in the copied spreadsheet (there is a bounded script in it). Can you explain why?

Comment: @Luther B Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your additional question. This is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for this. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, I would like to confirm your situation and think of it. Also it will also help other users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue. I'm glad.

Comment: I just published another post. I hope it is well explained. Thank you!

Comment: @Luther B Thank you for your response. I saw your new question, just now. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.