# Link to a specific sheet in published Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I see similar questionns has been asked multiple times before, but I cant seem to get them to work. I've also read that Google changed how their URLs are built up, so most of the solutions were deprecated unfortunately.

I'm looking for a link to a specific sheet of a workbook that has been published. I've made a simple workbook to test, and the published link looks like this:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRrmEbjecLvXhbm409pa6JJXZd_ZXTG8Zt6OevIUs5Axq5oxlCZKU0QXk-2lW05HyXJ2B4Bzy3bG-4L/pubhtml

As you can see there is a top menu to change between the sheets, but that doesn't affect the URL.

Is there any way I can get a URL to "Sheet2" directly? Or is that dependant on having the Sheet ID (I'm not the owner of said spreadsheet)?

Comment: In order to directly open the sheet except for the 1st tab, it is required to know the sheet ID of the sheet. Unfortunately, `2PACX-###` is not the Spreadsheet ID. So in order to retrieve the sheet ID, Spreadsheet ID is required. And also, from your question, it seems that the Spreadsheet is not yours. In this case, the Spreadsheet is required to be shared publicly. In this case, it is not the web publish. Please be careful this. So can you retrieve the Spreadsheet ID?

Comment: I only have access to the web publish, not the Spreadsheet ID.

So this seems impossible, even though I have access to the sheet in question I cant manage to link directly to it/access it directly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, I think that the sheet ID cannot be retrieved. By this, I think that the direct link for the sheet except for the 1st tab cannot be retrieved. I apologize for not coming up with other workaround yet.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Thats unfortunate and kind of a weird limitation in my eyes.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I came up with a workaround for achieving your goal. I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 4):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from `Sheet2` from the URL of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRrmEbjecLvXhbm409pa6JJXZd_ZXTG8Zt6OevIUs5Axq5oxlCZKU0QXk-2lW05HyXJ2B4Bzy3bG-4L/pubhtml`.
- The owner of this Spreadsheet is not you.
- You don't know the Spreadsheet ID and each sheet ID in the Spreadsheet. You know only the URL of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml`.
- Under above situation, you want to retrieve the direct URL of the sheet 2.

For above goal, how about this answer?

### Issue and workarounds:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that the Spreadsheet ID and each sheet ID cannot be directly retrieved from the URL of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml`. I think that this is the current specification. Also I think that this reason might be due to the security. So in order to achieve your goal, it is required to think of the workaround.

In this answer, as a workaround, I would like to achieve your goal using Web Apps created by Google Apps Script. When Web Apps is used, the directlink of `Sheet2` can be retrieved.

### Flow:

The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Download the Google Spreadsheet as a XLSX data from the URL of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml`.
2. Convert the XLSX data to Google Spreadsheet.
3. Publish the converted Google Spreadsheet to Web.
4. Retrieve the URLs of each sheet.

### Usage:

Please do the following flow.

#### 1. Create new project of Google Apps Script.

Sample script of Web Apps is a Google Apps Script. So please create a project of Google Apps Script.

If you want to directly create it, please access to https://script.new/. In this case, if you are not logged in Google, the log in screen is opened. So please log in to Google. By this, the script editor of Google Apps Script is opened.

#### 2. Prepare script.

Please copy and paste the following script (Google Apps Script) to the script editor. And **[please enable Google Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)**. This script is for the Web Apps.

```
function doGet(e) {
  const prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const ssId = prop.getProperty("ssId");
  if (ssId) {
    DriveApp.getFileById(ssId).setTrashed(true);
    prop.deleteProperty("ssId");
  }
  const inputUrl = e.parameter.url;
  const re = new RegExp("(https?:\\/\\/docs\\.google\\.com\\/spreadsheets\\/d\\/e\\/2PACX-.+?\\/)");
  if (!re.test(inputUrl)) return ContentService.createTextOutput("Wrong URL.");
  const url = `${inputUrl.match(re)[1]}pub?output=xlsx`;
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  const id = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, title: "temp"}, blob).id;
  prop.setProperty("ssId", id);
  Drive.Revisions.update({published: true, publishedOutsideDomain: true, publishAuto: true}, id, 1);
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets();
  const pubUrls = sheets.map(s => ({[s.getSheetName()]: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${id}/pubhtml?gid=${s.getSheetId()}`}));
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(pubUrls)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

- In this case, the GET method is used.
- In this script, when the below curl command is run, the Google Spreadsheet is downloaded as a XLSX data, and the XLSX data is converted to Google Spreadsheet. Then, the converted Spreadsheet is published to the web. By this, the direct links of each sheet can be retrieved.

  - Also, in this script, it supposes that the original Spreadsheet is changed. So if you run the curl command again, the existing Spreadsheet is deleted and new Spreadsheet is created by downloading from the original Spreadsheet. In this case, the URLs are updated.
  - So if the Spreadsheet is not changed, you can continue to use the retrieved URLs. Of course, you can also directly use the downloaded and converted Spreadsheet.

#### 3. Deploy Web Apps.

1. On the script editor, Open a dialog box by "Publish" -> "Deploy as web app".
2. Select **"Me"** for **"Execute the app as:"**.

   - By this, the script is run as the owner.
3. Select **"Anyone, even anonymous"** for **"Who has access to the app:"**.

   - In this case, no access token is required to be request. I think that I recommend this setting for your goal.
   - Of course, you can also use the access token. At that time, please set this to **"Anyone"**.
4. Click "Deploy" button as new "Project version".
5. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

   1. Click "Review Permissions".
   2. Select own account.
   3. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
   4. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
   5. Click "Allow" button.
6. Click "OK".
7. Copy the URL of Web Apps. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### 4. Run the function using Web Apps.

This is a sample curl command for requesting Web Apps. Please set your Web Apps URL.

```
curl -L "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?url=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRrmEbjecLvXhbm409pa6JJXZd_ZXTG8Zt6OevIUs5Axq5oxlCZKU0QXk-2lW05HyXJ2B4Bzy3bG-4L/pubhtml"
```

- In this case, the GET method is used at Web Apps side. So you can also directly access to the above URL using your browser.

### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- In this answer, I thought that you might use this from outside. So I used Web Apps. If you want to directly retrieved from the Google Apps Script, you can also use the following script.

  ```
  function myFunction() {
    const inputUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRrmEbjecLvXhbm409pa6JJXZd_ZXTG8Zt6OevIUs5Axq5oxlCZKU0QXk-2lW05HyXJ2B4Bzy3bG-4L/pubhtml";

    const prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    const ssId = prop.getProperty("ssId");
    if (ssId) {
      DriveApp.getFileById(ssId).setTrashed(true);
      prop.deleteProperty("ssId");
    }
    const re = new RegExp("(https?:\\/\\/docs\\.google\\.com\\/spreadsheets\\/d\\/e\\/2PACX-.+?\\/)");
    if (!re.test(inputUrl)) throw new Error("Wrong URL.");
    const url = `${inputUrl.match(re)[1]}pub?output=xlsx`;
    const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
    const id = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, title: "temp"}, blob).id;
    prop.setProperty("ssId", id);
    Drive.Revisions.update({published: true, publishedOutsideDomain: true, publishAuto: true}, id, 1);
    const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets();
    const pubUrls = sheets.map(s => ({[s.getSheetName()]: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${id}/pubhtml?gid=${s.getSheetId()}`}));
    console.log(pubUrls);  // You can see the URLs for each sheet at the log.
  }
  ```

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [publish a Google Spreadsheet through Google Apps Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56469509)

### Added:

As another workaround, when the original Spreadsheet is often changed, and the number of sheet is constant in the original Spreadsheet, and then, you want to retrieve only values, you can also use the following script. In this script, the URL is not changed even when the script is run again. So you can continue to use the URL.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const inputUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRrmEbjecLvXhbm409pa6JJXZd_ZXTG8Zt6OevIUs5Axq5oxlCZKU0QXk-2lW05HyXJ2B4Bzy3bG-4L/pubhtml";

  const re = new RegExp("(https?:\\/\\/docs\\.google\\.com\\/spreadsheets\\/d\\/e\\/2PACX-.+?\\/)");
  if (!re.test(inputUrl)) throw new Error("Wrong URL.");
  const url = `${inputUrl.match(re)[1]}pub?output=xlsx`;
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  const prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  let sheets;
  let ssId = prop.getProperty("ssId");
  if (ssId) {
    const temp = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, title: "tempSpreadsheet"}, blob).id;
    const tempSheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(temp).getSheets();
    sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets();
    tempSheets.forEach((e, i) => {
      const values = e.getDataRange().getValues();
      sheets[i].getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    });
    DriveApp.getFileById(temp).setTrashed(true);
  } else {
    ssId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, title: "copiedSpreadsheet"}, blob).id;
    Drive.Revisions.update({published: true, publishedOutsideDomain: true, publishAuto: true}, ssId, 1);
    prop.setProperty("ssId", ssId);
    sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets();
  }
  const pubUrls = sheets.map(s => ({[s.getSheetName()]: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ssId}/pubhtml?gid=${s.getSheetId()}`}));
  console.log(pubUrls);  // You can see the URLs for each sheet at the log.
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this thorough answer! 

Unfortunately, although the initial assumptions and goals are right, I dont think I can download an xlsx from the "2-PACKX-##/pubhtml" URL. There is no top menu.

And even if I could I'd say this solution is more advanced than I was looking for to be honost. Even though I can understand most of it, this seems like a pretty heavy workaround. 

Thanks again, sorry if this is disappointing.

Comment: @Mixy Thank you for replying. I think that you might misunderstand my answer. In order to download the Google Spreadsheet of the URL of `2-PACKX-##` as the XLSX data, this can be achieved by modifying the URL. This can be seen at my script. In your URL, you can download it as the XLSX data by accessing to `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRrmEbjecLvXhbm409pa6JJXZd_ZXTG8Zt6OevIUs5Axq5oxlCZKU0QXk-2lW05HyXJ2B4Bzy3bG-4L/pub?output=xlsx`. By this, all sheets are inluded. So I proposed this workaround.

Comment: I see. That works on the spreadsheet I created to mock up of the issue, but not on the original spreadsheet I'm trying to scrape. Hope you understand I dont want to post the original link here. 

Getting a File not found error with the link format /pub?output=xlsx 

After all looks like I have to find a new solution. Excel is crumbling with all the queries I'm adding so I have to find something more efficient I think

Comment: @Mixy Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I cannot understand about `Getting a File not found error with the link format /pub?output=xlsx`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Is there any way to send a direct message on this site? I could give you the link to the spreadsheet im trying to scrape, but I dont want to link it publicly.

Comment: @Mixy Thank you for replying. I cannot understand about your replying. In your question, you use the URL of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRrmEbjecLvXhbm409pa6JJXZd_ZXTG8Zt6OevIUs5Axq5oxlCZKU0QXk-2lW05HyXJ2B4Bzy3bG-4L/pubhtml`. My answer is a workaround for using this URL. If you want to use other endpoint, this is different from your this question. If I misunderstood your replying, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for trying :) The URL I posted in the question is just a mockup I made to test and to post here. The actual spreasheet I'm trying to scrape has a URL using the same format like this: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml` - but when I try to use the suggested format ending in `2PACX-###/pub?output=xlsx` I get the following notice: https://prnt.sc/s7t4ij

Comment: @Mixy Thank you for replying. I could understand about your replying. In this case, it seems that the format of endpoint is the same with your question. But the result is different. I could understand like this. I would like to confirm one thing. In this case, when your URL in your question is used for my sample script, it worked fine. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sorry to say I haven't attempted the script. If the endpoint `/pub?=output=xlsx` worked for the original sheet I could just put that link into Excel power query to scrape the second sheet directly. Then I wouldn't have to do the workaround. 

Seeing as the endpoints doesn't work for the original sheet I'm thinking its caused by some more restricted access placed on that sheet compared to my mockup.

Comment: @Mixy Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand whether my understanding is correct. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: I've created a temporary URL for the original sheet. https://www.temporary-url.com/0A266E

Would you check for an endpoint to get xlsx-download from this sheet please?

Comment: @Mixy Thank you for replying and providing the sample. I could correctly understand about your issue, and I could also confirm the error using `/pub?=output=xlsx`. But unfortunately, I cannot come up with the method for removing this error and other workaround soon. I apologize for my poor skill. When I came up with it, I would like to tell you.

Comment: Please dont appologize. Thank you so much for trying :)

Comment: @Mixy Thank you for replying. And also, this situation is the 1st time for me. So I would like to study more. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else, there might be another way to do this. You could use the `gid` query param present in the normal URL of the Gsheet for your selected sheet and append it to the end of your link like this `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRrmEbjecLvXhbm409pa6JJXZd_ZXTG8Zt6OevIUs5Axq5oxlCZKU0QXk-2lW05HyXJ2B4Bzy3bG-4L/pubhtml?gid=123456`