# Excel Power Query with Sheet 2 of a Google Spreadsheet as source?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, powerbi, spreadsheet, powerquery

I've been scraping parts of a published Google Spreadsheet into Excel using Power Query. I'm not the owner of the Google Spreadsheet, so I dont have the Spreadsheet ID.

To illustrate what I've got access to, I've made a mockup [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRrmEbjecLvXhbm409pa6JJXZd_ZXTG8Zt6OevIUs5Axq5oxlCZKU0QXk-2lW05HyXJ2B4Bzy3bG-4L/pubhtml)

So I want the Power Query in Excel to pull data from the second sheet, but I [can't find a direct link to the sheet I want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61437687/link-to-a-specific-sheet-in-published-google-sheet?noredirect=1#comment108682487_61437687).

Is there any way to have the power query "navigate" to the second sheet so I can access the data? Any other way I can scrape whats in the second sheet?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this workaround I proposed to your previous question useful for this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61437687/7108653

Comment: I have answered you in the other thread. 

Please note that if I was able to download the xlsx, I could pick up the download url of that file, and then add that as a web query in Excel. That would save me the workaround, but I dont think its possible.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the detail of `but I dont think its possible.`? I would like to understand about it.

Comment: What I meant was I didnt know/think the output=xlsx tag you showed me existed or would work at all. Thats very cool, but unfortunately doesn't work on the spreadsheet I'm looking for.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I cannot understand about `but unfortunately doesn't work on the spreadsheet I'm looking for.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?