# Dowload public Google Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, csv, google-sheets, export

Is there a way to quickly download a public google spreadsheet? The spreadsheet I want to download is the following:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSVcmgixKaP9LC-rrqS4D2rojIz48KwKA8QBmJloX1h7f8BkUloVuiw19eR2U5WvVT4InYgnPunUo49/pubhtml`

I tried various methods, for example replacing the `pubhtml` part of the url with `export?format=csv`, that didn't work.

I found one url that let's me download the first sheet:
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/${id}/pub?output=csv&id=${id}`

I want to download all sheets though, and adding a `&sheet=name` url-paramter didn't help. So how do I get this to work? Do I need to write code?

Comment: Assuming that you actually want to download the file as it is published to the web (publishing to the web is not the same as [making a file public by sharing it with everyone](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822)), you can download a specific sheet if you provide the corresponding `gid` parameter, like this: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/${id}/pub?output=csv&gid=${gid}`. Do you think that would be appropriate for you? If that's the case, I'd post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to download all sheets, how about downloading it as the XLSX file? In order to download your URL as the XLSX file, please modify as follows. In this case, the Spreadsheet ID is not required to be used. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61449794) is referred.

#### From:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSVcmgixKaP9LC-rrqS4D2rojIz48KwKA8QBmJloX1h7f8BkUloVuiw19eR2U5WvVT4InYgnPunUo49/pubhtml
```

#### To:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSVcmgixKaP9LC-rrqS4D2rojIz48KwKA8QBmJloX1h7f8BkUloVuiw19eR2U5WvVT4InYgnPunUo49/pub?output=xlsx
```

- When you access this URL using the browser, the XLSX file can be downloaded.
- Also you can download it using the curl command as follows.

  ```
    curl "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSVcmgixKaP9LC-rrqS4D2rojIz48KwKA8QBmJloX1h7f8BkUloVuiw19eR2U5WvVT4InYgnPunUo49/pub?output=xlsx" -o sample.xlsx
  ```

Comment: perfect, this is even better than having the csv file, thanks :).

Comment: @New2HTML Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.