# Access private published Google Spreadsheet by API

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

Is there an API to access the data of a spreadsheet that is private but published as a web page?

Comment: About `Is there an API to access the data of a spreadsheet that is private but published as a web page?`, can you provide the sample URL you have?

Comment: I have a spredsheet that is only accessible over the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR5Umrlc1Y4l3T4NJomM9OUXS6VtuOtZeHNGwFt5Wb--djvcQYUCdXCEMhsZGXKA-C8Tbdo0GpB_L5w/pubhtml but I can't access the spreadsheet content via an API because the original spreadsheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR5Umrlc1Y4l3T4NJomM9OUXS6VtuOtZeHNGwFt5Wb--djvcQYUCdXCEMhsZGXKA-C8Tbdo0GpB_L5w is not accessible. It's only published as a web page

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the case of URL like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml`, unfortunately, this Spreadsheet cannot be directly accessed by Sheets API because of no Spreadsheet ID. So it is required to use the workaround. About the workaround, is this workaround useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61449794/7108653 If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. It solved my problem

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your replying, I flagged your question as the duplicated question of https://stackoverflow.com/a/61449794