# How can one write to a publicly available Google sheet (without authorization) in Python?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, python-requests

I have full edit access to a Google Sheet not owned by me. I want to be able to write to the spreadsheet using Python without Google API authorization. I checked several available packages (`gdata`, `gspread` etc.) and seems all of them ask for the credentials.

I was also able to read the content of a spreadsheet without authorization using `requests` or `pd.read_csv()` by pandas (I tweaked the URL by changing the last part saying ...`edit#gid=`... to ...`export?format=csv&gid=`...). Yet, when sending a POST request to the same URL I received `200 status code` but the same old empty spreadsheet.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the values to the publicly shared Google Spreadsheet using python.
- In this case, you want to access to the Spreadsheet without authorization.

For this, how about this answer?

## Issue and workaround:

In order to put the values to the publicly shared Google Spreadsheet, the POST method is used. In this case, it is required to use the access token. On the other hand, in the case of the GET method, when the Sheets API is used, an API key can be used. And the endpoints like `exportLinks`, you can retrieve the values without the API key. These are the specification of Google side.

Under this condition, in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

## Pattern 1:

In this pattern, I would like to propose to access to the Spreadsheet using the access token retrieved from the service account. In this case, the script can be simpler.

### Sample script:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
worksheet = spreadsheet.sheet1
worksheet.update_acell('A1', 'sample')
```

- In this sample script, `sample` is put to the cell "A1" of the 1st tab in the publicly shared Spreadsheet using gspread.

## Pattern 2:

In this pattern, I would like to propose to access to the Spreadsheet using the Web Apps created by Google Apps Script as the wrapper API. In this case, the python script is more simpler.

### Usage:

Please do the following flow.

#### 1. Create new project of Google Apps Script.

Sample script of Web Apps is a Google Apps Script. So please create a project of Google Apps Script.

If you want to directly create it, please access to https://script.new/. In this case, if you are not logged in Google, the log in screen is opened. So please log in to Google. By this, the script editor of Google Apps Script is opened.

#### 2. Prepare script.

Please copy and paste the following script (Google Apps Script) to the script editor. And **[please enable Google Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)**. This script is for the Web Apps.

```
function doPost(e) {
  try {
    const spreadsheetId = e.parameter.spreadsheetId;
    const obj = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    const resource = obj.body;
    const range = obj.arguments.range;
    const valueInputOption = obj.arguments.valueInputOption;
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(resource, spreadsheetId, range, {valueInputOption: valueInputOption});
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");
  } catch(e) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
  }
}
```

- In this case, the POST method is used.
- In this sample script, as a test script, the values are put to the Spreadsheet using the method of spreadsheets.values.update in Sheets API.

#### 3. Deploy Web Apps.

1. On the script editor, Open a dialog box by "Publish" -> "Deploy as web app".
2. Select **"Me"** for **"Execute the app as:"**.

   - By this, the script is run as the owner.
3. Select **"Anyone, even anonymous"** for **"Who has access to the app:"**.

   - In this case, no access token is required to be request. I think that I recommend this setting for your goal.
   - Of course, you can also use the access token. At that time, please set this to **"Anyone"**.
4. Click "Deploy" button as new "Project version".
5. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

   1. Click "Review Permissions".
   2. Select own account.
   3. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
   4. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
   5. Click "Allow" button.
6. Click "OK".
7. Copy the URL of Web Apps. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### 4. Run the function using Web Apps.

This is a sample python script for requesting Web Apps. Please set your Web Apps URL, Spreadsheet ID and range.

```
import json
import requests

spreadsheet_id = '###'  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
body = {
    "arguments": {"range": "Sheet1!A1", "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED"},
    "body": {"values": [["sample"]]}
}
url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?spreadsheetId=' + spreadsheet_id
res = requests.post(url, json.dumps(body), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
print(res.text)
```

- In this sample script, `sample` is put to the cell "A1" of the 1st tab in the publicly shared Spreadsheet.
- In this case, no authorization is required in the python script, because it has already been done when Web Apps is deployed.

## Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

## References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [publish a Google Spreadsheet through Google Apps Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56469509)
- [spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, Tanaike! I have several question though.
1) in case of Pattern 1, does not it still assume that I have to create credentials and authorize? If not, then where do I obtain the credentials.json file?
2) in case of Pattern 2, might be silly question, but does it mean I have to create a separate web app each time I want to perform a write operation on a new Spreadsheet? Or i can use an app for dealing with any spreadsheet that my account has write access to?

Comment: @Hrant Davtyan Thank you for replying. I answer to questions in your replying. A1. No. In this case, the service account is used, you can create it. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) When the service account is used, the authorization process using the browser is not required. A2. No. The pattern 2 uses Spreadsheet ID in the request. So even when you created new Spreadsheet, you can continue to use the same Web Apps. If I misunderstood your questions, I apologize.

Comment: @Hrant Davtyan Thank you for replying.