# publish file GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Hello is it possible to publish via google app script the file?
Generally I want to embed via code google drawing into spreadsheet.
In order to imort it using Image formula with link to spreadsheet i need to publish the google drawing
(File -> publish to the web) and then paste the publishing
link, I would like to automate it

I know it is possible to insert drawing as an image by converting it to blob ... but it would make the image static and would not change when the original file changes (and I have this behaviour when using Image() function )

Answer (score 2):

### There is a workaround for doing it with the [Advanced drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)

- [Enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) the advanced Drive Service
- Use [Drive revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions)
- Get the last revision of the file
- Set the properties `published` and `publishAuto` to true and update the revision.
- The latter will ensure that all subsequent versions of the file (when the file changes) will be automatically published.

**Sample:**

```js
function publishToWeb(){ 
  var fileId = 'ID OF YOUR GOOGLE DRAWING'; 
  var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId); 
  var items = revisions.items; 
  var lastRevisionId =items[items.length-1].id; 
  var lastRevision = Drive.Revisions.get(fileId, lastRevisionId); 
  lastRevision.published = true;
  lastRevision.publishAuto = true;
  lastRevision.publishedOutsideDomain = true;
  Drive.Revisions.update(lastRevision, fileId, lastRevisionId); 
}
```

Comment: Thank You , yes File is published, HOvewer when I try to return lastRevision.publishedLink or Drive.Revisions.update(lastRevision, fileId, lastRevisionId).publishedLink   it returns null, how to obtain publishing link?

Comment: As for retrieving the link, unfortunetely there is a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/73536382) (which you should "star" to increase visibility). There are [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56469761/11599789) for creating the published link manually for google spreadsheets, not sure if it also works for Google drawings.

Comment: I tried to use this template - https://docs.google.com/drawings/pub?key=### drawingId ###      like that https://docs.google.com/drawings/pub?key=1hoR667VTu861Y4zkA1Zw4RX41I1BfTIlY-gWmoJxCcc unfortunatelly it do not work do I miss sth or It will not work on drawings ?

Comment: I aslo tried and for me it didn't work neither. It is a hardcoded workaround that seems to work for Google Sheets, but apparently not for drawings. So while with the code above you can publish a drawing, unfortunately you won't be able able to retrieve the link automatically before the bug gets fixed... I can only recommend you to star the existing issue and maybe comment on it to remind Google that it has not been fixed yet.